# Racket map cartesian product thing

Tags: dictionary, racket, cartesian-product

In racket a higher order function like map used on two lists does this:

```
(map list '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3))
> '( (1 1) (2 2) (3 3) )
```

But I would like a cartesian-product thing like this:

```
'( (1 1) (1 2) (1 3) (2 1) (2 2) (2 3) (3 1) (3 2) (3 3) )
```

How can I achieve this? Preferably with higher order functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a method that totally uses higher-order functions (`foldr`, `append-map`, and `map`; now also with `compose1`, `curry`, and `curryr`):

```
(define (cartesian-product . lists)
  (foldr (lambda (a b)
           (append-map (compose1 (curryr map b) (curry cons))
                       a))
         '(())
         lists))
```

Pardon the terrible parameter names. One day I'll come up with something good. :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
> (require unstable/list)
> (cartesian-product '(1 2 3) '(a b c))
'((1 a) (1 b) (1 c) (2 a) (2 b) (2 c) (3 a) (3 b) (3 c))
```

See http://docs.racket-lang.org/unstable/list.html#%28def._%28%28lib._unstable%2Flist..rkt%29._cartesian-product%29%29

Comment: Well, it's unstable, which means it won't be portable between versions. :-(

Comment: I don't expect it to go away :-)

Comment: Right, but the required import might change, so your code still won't be stable between versions. ;-)

Comment: True. It would be easy for unstable/list simply to reexport the moved identifier though.

Comment: They (the Racket maintainers) could, in theory, but why would they? It's unstable, after all.

Comment: It just shows the unstable collection was a bad idea in the first place. However with the new package system, I expect collections that previously went into unstable simply to be available at their author's Github repository.

Comment: Chris: s/why would they/why would you/  ... which is to say, I think Jens can probably make this happen.

Comment: @soegaard Agree, I think that versioned packages would be more useful (re allowing subject-to-change interfaces). Oh wait, PLaneT had those! (I'm not familiar enough with the new package system had that too, but since it links to GitHub, I'd certainly hope so—wherein each version links to its own git commit.)

Comment: @JohnClements If that were actually to be the case, then like Jens said, "unstable" seems like a not-very-well-thought-out idea. I mean, real code is really supposed to treat unstable as invisible, surely, and not actually depend on anything in it to, y'know, be stable. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In SCIP chapter 2.2.3 "Sequences as Conventional Interfaces, authors show us a general way to approach such problem. There is actually a similar example. The book uses flatmap as a common abstraction. `The combination of mapping and accumulating with append is so common in this sort of program that we will isolate it as a separate procedure: flatmap`. Here is a solution using flatmap:

```
>(define (flatmap proc seq)                                                                                                                                    
  (foldr append '() (map proc seq)))   
>(flatmap                                                                                                                                  
   (lambda (x)                                                                                                                              
     (map                                                                                                                                   
       (lambda (y) (list y x))                                                                                                               
       '(1 2 3)))                                                                                                                            
   '(a b c))                                                                                                                                
'((1 a) (2 a) (3 a) (1 b) (2 b) (3 b) (1 c) (2 c) (3 c))
```